# How to "revert" object along some axis?

Tags: modeling

I can just scale the object passing its pivot, but then the scale value gets negative along that axis is that I don`t totally need. Are there any other ways to obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mirror transform to 'revert' your object.
And if you don't like negative scale, just apply the scale.

Mirror object: *Object > Mirror*
Apply Scale: *Object > Apply > Scale*

*How to mirror an object and apply scale.*
[image]

**Note:**
Applying negative scale can flip your normals orientation.
Check your normals after that, so they're not inverted.